# Moving a UIImageView with a UIButton

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton, mapbox

I am rather new to Xcode and iOS development but have been enjoying the challenge so far.

I have run into an issue where I am attempting to move a `UIImageView` I have created programmatically on top of a MapBox mapView.

I would like to move this `UIImageView` with a `UIButton` by a measure of pixels, with the UIButton being on top of the mapView.

This is the code I have so far in my ViewController.m:

```
    [self.view addSubview:mapView];

    UIImageView* ship;

    ship=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 200, 40, 40)];
    UIImage * image;
    image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"spaceShip"];
    [ship setImage:image];
    ship.alpha = 0.75;
    [self.view addSubview:ship];

    UIButton *upButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    upButton.frame = CGRectMake(150, 250, 40, 40);
    upButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    [upButton setTitle:@"UP" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [upButton addTarget:ship action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:upButton];

}

- (IBAction)moveUp {
    ship.center = CGPointMake(ship.center.x, ship.center.y -10);
}
```

Could anyone show me how to get this upButton to recognize and move my `UIImageView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that ship is a local variable that you create in the first block of code. When that code block goes out of scope, ship will be nil, so when you try to set it's center in the button method, it won't work. You need to create a property for ship, and use that instead.

Your other problem is that when you add the action to your button, you call it buttonPressed:, but the method you implemented is moveUp. So, if you create a property called ship, then your action method should be,

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *) sender {
    self.ship.center = CGPointMake(self.ship.center.x, self.ship.center.y -10);
}
```